# Simple tags system in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm making simple tagging function in my laravel project. I've made table `tags`

```
id | tag
```

also I have table `items`

```
id | title | description
```

and third table `item_tag` which will hold the id of `item` and id of `tag`

In my Item model I've added this relation

```
public function tags() {

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'item_tag');
}
```

and the relation in Tag model

```
public function itemTags() {

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item', 'item_tag');

}
```

Item creating controller has `create()` for the view and `store()` for storing item

```
public function create(){

   $allTags = Tag::all();
   return view('items.create', compact('allTags'));       
}

public function store( ItemRequest $request ){

    $item = new Item;
    $item->title = $request['title'];
    $item->description = $request['description'];        
    $item->save();

    return redirect()->route('items');       
}
```

On form tags selection with multiple ( not sure if is correct way of doing it like this )

```
<div class="form-group">
     {!! Form::label('tags', 'Tags', array('class'=> 'col-sm-2 control-label')) !!}                        
     <div class="col-sm-10">
         <select name="tags[]" class="form-control select2" id="tags" multiple>
         @foreach($allTags as $tag)
              <option value="{!!$tag->id!!}">{!!$tag->tag!!}</option>
         @endforeach
         </select>
     </div>
</div>
```

My question is how to grab and save tags id and item id in pivot table? And then show tags on the page on the item?

Update

in `dd($item)` I see this in relations

```
  #relations: array:3 [▼
    "tags" => Collection {#330 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        0 => Tag {#329 ▼
          #table: "tags"
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #fillable: array:1 [▶]
          #connection: null
          #keyType: "int"
          #perPage: 15
          +incrementing: true
          +timestamps: true
          #attributes: array:10 [▼
            "id" => 5
            "tag" => "testTag"
            "title" => null
            "subtitle" => null
            "page_image" => null
            "meta_description" => null
            "layout" => null
            "reverse_direction" => null
            "created_at" => "2017-01-25 06:52:59"
            "updated_at" => "2017-01-25 06:52:59"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, you want to detach all tags from an item and attach only ones that user has added in the form. In this case, use [`sync()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) method.

> The sync method accepts an array of IDs to place on the intermediate table. Any IDs that are not in the given array will be removed from the intermediate table. So, after this operation is complete, only the IDs in the given array will exist in the intermediate table

For example:

```
$item = new Item;
$item->title = $request['title'];
$item->description = $request['description'];        
$item->save();

// If some tags are new, you should create them here first and get their IDs from a DB.

$item->tags()->sync($request->tags);
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy. So simple and I've missed it. So now pivot table is updated with tags. About second question currently I display single item with this query: `$item =  Item::find($id);`. How to grab now the tags also?

Comment: @VLS use eager loading `$item = Item::with('tags')->find($id);`

Comment: Thanks again but have you any idea why `$item->tag`, `$item->tags` return `NULL` when I try to show them on page?

Comment: It's returning `null`

Comment: I see it on `dd($item)`.. I've updated my question what I see there. 1 tag . this is correct since I have one tag in pivot table for this item

Comment: @VLS you've shown result for `$items` not and item. So you'll need to iterate over items first and then iterate over tags like `@foreach($items as $item)  @foreach($item->tags as $tag)  {{ $tag->tag }}  @endforeach @endforeach`  Looks like not all items have tags.

Comment: My mistake in question update.. should be `dd($item)` not `items`. I've edited it in question.  So I've tried your example with one foreach like `@foreach($item as $item_tags) {{ $item_tags->tag }} @endforeach` but is still NULL

Comment: @VLS you should iterate over tags, not item `@foreach($item->tags as $tag) {{ $tag->tag }} @endforeach`

Comment: Strange thing is also that I expect there one tag but I see in source empty html for 4 tags

Comment: Now another error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: Probably because `{{ dd($item->tags) }}` return `null` but why

Comment: BTW There is no FK's in pivot table, only indexes.. could this be the problem?

Comment: Also I've checked last query and it's showed me this in array `select * from items where items.id = 13 limit 1 / select tags.*, item_tag.item_id as pivot_item_id, item_tag.tag_id as pivot_tag_id from tags inner join item_tag on tags.id = item_tag.tag_id where item_tag.item_id in (13)` and when I run it in phpmysql I got correct result

Comment: @VLS I don't know wy is this happening. If you would use many items, it could be empty tags for some items. But if you're saying that `dd($item)` shows you non-empty `tags` relation, but at the same time `dd($item->tags)` shows `null`, I just can't imagine what it can be.

Comment: Thanks fro the help. Anyway I will try to find what is happening. Just last question: do I need FK between pivot table and tags table?

Comment: It should work without FK constraint, I mean with simple keys. The pivot table should have `item_id` and `tag_id` keys

Comment: pivot table has `item_id` and `tag_id` but in items table the key is `id` not `item_id` same for tags

Comment: You shouldn't have any keys in `Item` and `Tag` models, only in the pivot table.

Comment: I mean my primary key in `item` table is `id` not `item_id` like is in the column in pivot table.