# Data not coming from 2 tables + 1 pivot table in laravel relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Here is the thread for reference: [Simple tags system in Laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41846724/simple-tags-system-in-laravel-5-2)

I can't make those tags displayed on the page. It's always return `null` here is the source I have:

Item model

```
public function tags() {

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'item_tag');
}
```

Tag model

```
class Tag extends Model {

    protected $table = 'tags';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [
        'tag'
    ];

    public function itemTags() {

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item', 'item_tag');

    }    

}
```

ItemController

```
public function show($id)
{
     $item = Item::with('tags')->find($id);
     return view('item', compact('item'));
}
```

And the view

```
@foreach($item->tags() as $showTags)         
      {{ $showTags->tag }}                  
@endforeach
```

`dd($item)` return two tags in relation so I assume they are there in collection but the return is either empty space on the page or `null`.

```
Item {#322 ▼
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #table: "items"
  #fillable: array:9 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #keyType: "int"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:25 [▶]
  #original: array:25 [▶]
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "tags" => Collection {#332 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        0 => Tag {#330 ▶}  // tag 1
        1 => Tag {#331 ▶}  // tag 2
      ]
    }
  ]
   ...
}
```

Please suggest what can be the problem.

Comment: Does your Tag model have a property named `tag`?

Comment: @Jerodev I've updated my question with full `Tag` model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After eager loading you don't need to invoke the relationship, its available as a collection:

```
// $item->tags not $item->tags() since its a collection
@foreach($item->tags as $showTags)         
      {{ $showTags->tag }}                  
@endforeach 

// if you don'nt eager load, then you can call the relationship
@foreach($item->tags()->get() as $showTags)
...
```

Comment: Hm, I've tried this many times and it didn't worked because I always got `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` I've changed the name of the function in model to `taggs` and not it's working with `$item->taggs`.. Anything special in this word `tag` and that's why is causing the problem?

Comment: @VLS No, tag is not a reserved keyword. Have you tried the second method? not eager loading?

Comment: Yes, second method is working fine. Just when I try `$item->tags()` show empty/null and `$item->tags` show `Invalid argument...`. Very strange to me.

Comment: @VLS so my code worked then? You've got `null` when you've used `{{ dd($item->tags()) }}`?

Comment: This one `@foreach($item->tags()->get() as $showTags)` is working perfectly. `@foreach($item->tags as $showTags)` this one doesn't work as I get `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` but if I change `tag` in model, query and foreach to any other word for example `taggs` is working also perfectly. There is something which I can't see..

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Yes, null. Now everything work as expected. Thanks to both of you.